# Is it possible to inject mocks through import statements (Mockito)?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

In a class I import some packages, but I want to mock some of the methods in the packages. For example:

```
import com.MyObject;
...
    MyObject.myMethod();
```

How do I mock MyObject's myMethod?

Comment: If it is a `static` method, use PowerMock.

Comment: You mean how do you [mock a static method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21105403/mocking-static-methods-with-mockito). All objects you use need to be imported, so importing has nothing to do with anything here.

Comment: @Kayaman Right, but is it possible to just tell mockito to replace the imported library with something else?

Comment: @michalk I cannot use Powermockito

Comment: Then don't use static methods, they complicate testing.